# Why is the variable "client" not working as it should?

Tags: python, client, bots, discord, discord.py

I am making a discord bot with discord.py and am wondering why my `client` variable isn't working. I know it has something to do with global variables but I can't seem to get it to work. I have two scripts that are connected via something i think is called "cogs". Here is my first script (the main one).

```
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands

token = # For obvious reasons not shown
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!")

@client.command()
async def load(ctx, extention):
    client.load_extension(f'cogs.{extention}')

@client.command()
async def unload(ctx, extention):
    client.unload_extension(f'cogs.{extention}')

@client.command()
async def reload(ctx, extention):
    client.unload_extension(f'cogs.{extention}')
    client.load_extension(f'cogs.{extention}')

for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
    if filename.endswith('.py'):
        client.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')

client.run(token)
```

Everything works great when it comes to this script but when it comes to my second script something is wrong.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import time as t
import random

class Coinflip(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.command(aliases=['coinflip'])
    async def cf(self, ctx, cfChoice: str):

        # Randomize and set choice to upper case letters
        cfChoice = cfChoice.upper()
        cfResults = random.choice(['RED', 'BLUE'])

        # Get the user who sent the message
        user = client.get_user(ctx.message.author.id)

        t.sleep(1)

        if cfChoice == 'RED' or cfChoice == 'BLUE':
            # WIN
            if cfChoice == cfResults:
                # Send result in the channel
                await ctx.send(f'It is {cfResults.lower()}!')
                # Send a DM to the person
                await user.send('You won on coinflip! Well done.')

            # LOST
            elif cfChoice != cfResults:
                # Send result in the channel
                await ctx.send(f'It is {cfResults.lower()}!')
                # Send a DM to the person
                await user.send('You lost on coinflip! Good luck next time.')

        # NOT VALID CHOICE
        else:
            # Send a DM to the person
            await user.send(f'"{cfChoice.lower()}" is not valid! Try again! [red/blue]')


def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Coinflip(client))
```

The `client` variable works fine everywhere exept here `user = client.get_user(ctx.message.author.id)`. It sais "undefined variable 'client'". Thank you for your help.

Comment: I forgot to mention that it is a coinflip bot :)

Comment: Use `self.client`!